# ssrs - embed html id, name or otherwise identify a table or element

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have a ssrs report server which generates reports, which I would like to embed into other pages.

I have found that I can embed the entire report in an iframe quite easily, but I would like to hide everything inside of this iframe except for the table I need. This requires setting an attribute in the table so that I can select it. Alternatively, retrieving the client ID of the table after the fact.

However, I have not been able to find a way to embed some kind of identifier into the tablix table such that it can be easily selected. Ideally I'd like to just add a `name` or `id` attribute to the table but this doesn't seem possible.

Is there some way around this?

Comment: "This requires a ..." ?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and use a report parameter as workaround. I created a new report parameter (under **Available values > Specify values**) with the following values:

```
'Label        'Value
=Tablix1         1
=Tablix2         2
```

Now at the tablix under **Tablix properties > Visibility > Show or hide based on expression** I added this expression:

```
=IIF(Parameters!ReportParamaterTablixChoice.Value = 1, True, False)
```

This tablix gets now only displayed if the user selects the value `Tablix1` from the parameter. So basically you can see it as unique `ID` for different tablixes from which you can chose now.